# Prevent browse to render HTML when using htmlentities() function in PHP

Tags: php, html

I want to display the output of PHP echo statement on the browser. The result is output of 
`htmlentities()` function of PHP.

```
$str = "A 'quote' is <b>bold</b>";
// Expected Outputs: A 'quote' is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;
echo "<textarea>".htmlentities($str)."</textarea>";
// Expected Outputs: A &#039;quote&#039; is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;
echo "<textarea>".htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES)."</textarea>";
```

Apparently, it is giving me

`A 'quote' is <b>bold</b>` inside my `<textarea>`

Please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double-escape it.

```
echo "<textarea>".htmlentities(htmlentities($str))."</textarea>";
```

The purpose of `htmlentities()` is to prevent HTML being parsed as-is. But you actually want to display the HTML entities as-is, so you need to re-escape them in turn.

Answer (score 1):

BalusC's solution will work, or you could just write your string as you want it to appear and continue to use `htmlentities` only once:

```
    $str = "A 'quote' is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;";

    echo "<textarea>".htmlentities($str)."</textarea>";

    // Expected Outputs: A 'quote' is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;
    // Actual Output   : A 'quote' is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;
```